# Good practices for protecting a machine certificate against extraction

Tags: certificates, hardware-token

Consider the following scenario:

- You are providing VPN access for a number of machines running Windows 10.
- The machines are configured and hardened according to company standards.
- You rely on machine certificates for authentication to the VPN gateway.
- You want to prevent users (or someone impersonating a legitimate user) from extracting the certificate (and private key) from their machines and transferring it to another machine.
- Some of your users need to have a level of permissions sufficient to extract a flat-file certificate/key pair from the machine.

What are good practices to prevent extraction of machine credentials? Approaches that come to mind:

- Use the TPM for key storage. Questions here—does Windows support using the TPM as a key store? How much would it take to transfer the TPM hardware itself to a different machine?
- Use a USB token for key storage. Question here—tokens are designed to be pluggable; is there an effective way of preventing it from being used on another machine?

Comment: This seems like a "[**Don't Roll Your Own Crypto!**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/61443)" is in order. I am not a Windows admin expert, but this seems like a use-case that should be well-supported by Microsoft CAPI.

Answer (score 1):

> You want to prevent users (or someone impersonating a legitimate user) from extracting the certificate (and private key) from their machines

You should use a smart card

The private key is generated by the smart card, and **can never leave the smart card** (there is no API to "extract" it). Encryption, decryption, signing is done by the chip on the smart card

> tokens are designed to be pluggable; is there an effective way of preventing it from being used on another machine?

If old-school desktops are an option, then you simply lock the computer in a case

> Some of your users need to have a level of permissions sufficient to extract a flat-file certificate/key pair from the machine

Why?

Comment: ... I really don't see how locking the computer in a case prevents the user (or malware on that machine) from, say, emailing the private key. I feel this isn't really an answer, so much as telling the OP that their requirements are wrong.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Thanks for the downvote. A smart card prevents the user from extracting the key. A locked case prevents the user from removing the smart card

Comment: I see. I've removed my downvote, but I still don't think this answers the question; VPNs are usually used to connect from off-site, so I highly doubt that "lock it in a cabinet" is viable.

(minor edit, "smartcard" != "HSM")

Comment: Re the permissions: of course, being able to extract keys is not a requirement per se, but some users need extended privileges which, as a side-effect, give them the ability to extract flat-file certificates from the machine. Hence the assumption that no file on disk is secure from being read by the user, and any solution needs to consider that.